# I seem to get multiple errors when running this code

Tags: python

```
 import numpy as np
  set up empty list to append to, and define threshold string length
  long_names = ()
  short_names = []
  threshold = 4
 % list of strings
 names = [‘dog’ , ‘cat’, ‘mouse’, ‘horse’, ‘cow’, ‘elephant’]
 % loop through list of strings, check length and append to relevant list
 for i in np.arange(1,len(names),1):    
               if len(names[i]) > threshold:
                              long_list.append(names[i])
                 elseif:
                             short_list.append(names[i])
    print(“length of long_names = , long_names”)
    print(“length of short names = ”, len(short_names))
```

Im pretty new to python, and I am self learning at the moment.

Comment: It would help if you posted the actual errors... For starters, what are those `%`? A comment in Python is started with a `#`

Comment: How are you self-learning? Did you take a look at the official [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)?

Comment: There are a lot of syntactic errors here -- I'd suggest starting with a much smaller script so you can get something running (always start with `print("Hello world!")`, and working your way up to more complex concepts so that you can fix errors as they're encountered rather than ending up in this situation where there are so many things wrong it's hard to know where to begin.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with this code. The indentations are off, there are uncommented lines that clearly contain comments instead of code, the quotation marks are wrong, you spelled `np.arrange()`wrong, and `elseif` should spell `elif`. EDIT: Sorry, `arange` is correct. My bad. Thanks Tomerikoo

Comment: @MartinWettstein it actually is [`arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html)... Not an error, it is just unnecessary and could be replaced with the built-in [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)...

Comment: I don't see why this was closed as "need details" when there were already answers dealing with all of the sytnax isssues. What details are needed?

Comment: `arange()` is a Python 2.x function (that no longer exists in Python 3.x), so you need to tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Why `arange()` it doesn't exists in python 3.x? and it's a numpy function? I tried the code with `arange()` and it works fine!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's just syntactical errors and also errors with variables names and definitions!

You should read more about python rules!

Take a look at [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)

Here is the working code for you:

```
import numpy as np
#set up empty list to append to, and define threshold string length
long_names = []
short_names = []
threshold = 4
# list of strings
names = ['dog' , 'cat', 'mouse', 'horse', 'cow', 'elephant']
# loop through list of strings, check length and append to relevant list
for i in np.arange(1,len(names),1):    
    if len(names[i]) > threshold:
        long_names.append(names[i])
    else:
        short_names.append(names[i])
print('length of long_names = ', len(long_names))
print('length of short names = ', len(short_names))
```

Comment: @tdelaney I edited it to make it good.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to figure out what you wanted to do so i just edit your code.

```
import numpy as np
#set up empty list to append to, and define threshold string length
long_names = []
short_names = []
threshold = 4
#list of strings
names = ['dog' , 'cat', 'mouse', 'horse', 'cow', 'elephant']
#loop through list of strings, check length and append to relevant list
for i in np.arange(1,len(names),1):    
    if len(names[i]) > threshold:
        long_names.append(names[i])
    else:
        short_names.append(names[i])
print("length of long_names = ", long_names)
print("length of short names = ", len(short_names))
```